# Getting an Alexa Slot value out of an intent

Tags: json, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm working to build an Alexa skill and have run into a roadblock on getting my slot values out of the intent object. The intent object JSON looks like so:

```
"intent": {
    "name": "string",
    "slots": {
      "string": {
        "name": "string",
        "value": "string"
      }
   }
}
```

My question is what will that first "string" value be to identify the slots? The documentation has this:

```
A map of key-value pairs that further describes what the user meant based on a predefined intent schema. The map can be empty.

    The key is a string that describes the name of the slot. Type: string.
    The value is an object of type slot. Type: object. See Slot Object.
```

Does this mean the key to get the slot is the name I set in the Interaction Model? The only reason I'm hesitant to think that is because we already have a name object in the slot, which is definitely the name of the slot -- so if the way to access a specific slot was via the name, the name parameter would be redundant (you already know the name from accessing the slot.)

Does anyone know how I go about accessing individual slot values in an Alexa skill?

I'm using NodeJS for this skill by the way.

Answer (score 18):

Since I had a lot of trouble with this, a more concrete answer (now) is:

```
'PersonIntent': function () {
    var text = 'Hello ' + this.event.request.intent.slots.FirstPerson.value;

    this.emit(':tell', text);
},
```

With this intent schema:

```
{
    "intents": [
        {
            "intent": "PersonIntent",
            "slots": [
                {
                    "name": "FirstPerson",
                    "type": "AMAZON.DE_FIRST_NAME"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `this` in `this.emit()` and `this.event...` etc.?

Comment: The this Keyword. In JavaScript, the thing called this, is the object that "owns" the JavaScript code. The value of this, when used in a function, is the object that "owns" the function.The value of this, when used in an object, is the object itself. The this keyword in an object constructor does not have a value.

Comment: How to user `this.emit` in php. I am doing code in php and i need this functionality to execute.

Answer (score 12):

This is an example of an intent with your structure:

```
"intent": {
    "name": "MovieIntent",
    "slots": {
     "string": {
        "name": "Movie",
        "value": "Titanic"
     }
  }
}
```

So, this means that the Intent you are using is named: Movie Intent (the one you set in your Interaction Model). And you will get the value this way:

```
var movieSlot = intent.slots.Movie.value;
```

Answer (score 6):

As of Jul, 2019: You can access it in your intent handler as follows

```
if (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.SLOTNAME === undefined) {
    text = 'Hello! SLOTNAME not identified';
} else {
    text = 'Hello!, SLOTNAME identified: ' + handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.SLOTNAME.value;
}
```

Replace `SLOTNAME` with your slot name.
It is also very important that `undefined` is just as it is as an object, and not `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume we have a intent with name create meeting request in interaction model.

```
"intents": [
    {
        "name": "CreateMeetingRequest",
        "slots": [
            {
                "name": "meetingdate",
                "type": "AMAZON.DATE",
                "samples": [
                    "{meetingdate} at {meetingTime} for {duration}",
                    "{meetingdate} at {meetingTime}",
                    "{meetingdate} and {meetingTime}",
                    "{meetingdate}"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "meetingTime",
                "type": "AMAZON.TIME",
                "samples": [
                    "{meetingTime} for {duration}",
                    "{meetingTime}"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "duration",
                "type": "AMAZON.DURATION",
                "samples": [
                    "{duration}"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "subject",
                "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery",
                "samples": [
                    "{subject}"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "toName",
                "type": "AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME",
                "samples": [
                    "{toName}"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "samples": [
            "meeting invite",
            "set up meeting",
            "setup meeting",
            "{meetingdate} at {meetingTime}",
            "create meeting with {toName}",
            "schedule a meeting with {toName} on {meetingdate} at {meetingTime} for {duration}",
            "Setup meeting with {toName}",
            "create meeting",
            "Setup meeting on {meetingdate} at {meetingTime}",
            "Setup new meeting",
            "create meeting request"
        ]
    }
]
```

And you wanna access it in lambda code. You can use below lines.

```
'CreateMeetingRequest': function () {
    const toName = (this.event.request.intent.slots.toName.value ? this.event.request.intent.slots.toName.value.toLowerCase() : null);
    const subject = (this.event.request.intent.slots.subject.value ? this.event.request.intent.slots.subject.value.toLowerCase() : null);
    const meetingdate = (this.event.request.intent.slots.meetingdate.value ? this.event.request.intent.slots.meetingdate.value : null);
    const meetingTime = (this.event.request.intent.slots.meetingTime.value ? this.event.request.intent.slots.meetingTime.value : null);
    const duration = (this.event.request.intent.slots.duration.value ? this.event.request.intent.slots.duration.value : null);

    console.log("toName:",toName,", meetingdate:",meetingdate,", meetingTime:", meetingTime);
    //your business logic
},
```

`this` is the Object contains complete JSON request from  alexa. So you can access any slot by using slotname
Eg: if we want to access `subject slot` then we can use `this.event.request.intent.slots.subject.value`