# Using slots in Alexa implementation

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am trying to build an Alexa skill set and would like to make use of slots.

```
handle(handlerInput);
const request =
   handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
const responseBuilder =
   handlerInput.responseBuilder;
let sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();

let say = "";

let slotStatus = "";
let resolvedSlot;

let slotValues = getSlotValues(
   request.intent.slots
);
// getSlotValues returns .heardAs, .resolved, and .isValidated for each slot, according to request slot status codes ER_SUCCESS_MATCH, ER_SUCCESS_NO_MATCH, or traditional simple request slot without resolutions

// console.log('***** slotValues: ' +  JSON.stringify(slotValues, null, 2));
//   SLOT: carvariant
if (slotValues && slotValues.carvariant) {
   say =
      "Good Choice! For an {carvariant}, I would suggest Kia Seltos";
} else {
   say =
      "Sorry! We do not have that category of car available.";
}
```

where {carvariant} is the slot that I created having values as "sedan,SUV,hatchback" but it return nothing.
I also tried `say = 'Good Choice! For an ${slotValues.carvariant.heardAs}, I would suggest Kia Seltos'` but it didn't pick the values from slots created.

Comment: what is Car variant suppose to say? Can you share your JSON value similar to


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887451/getting-an-alexa-slot-value-out-of-an-intent

Comment: Car variant should return one of the values from the custom slot created.
`"types": [
        {
          "name": "carvariant",
          "values": [
            {
              "name": {
                "value": "Hatchback"
              }
            },
            {
              "name": {
                "value": "Sedan"
              }
            },
            {
              "name": {
                "value": "SUV"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]`